# What exactly do Volley "response" and "error" contain?

Tags: android, android-volley

I can't really understand this concept . My knowledge on webservices and oop is limited. Lets say that I set up a string request and pass a very simple database connection php script url to it. What would the volley response and error contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Volley follows standard [HTTP response codes][1].

[1]: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html .

When the server responds with a HTTP OK - 200 Code it goes through the onResponse Callback . For all error code it would go through the onError Callback.

Comment: I added an echo to my simple php script for testing purpose. If connection to db happens , it echoes "success" . Then i passed volley result data to a textview. That textview contained the success message along with some other stuff i didnt understand